# Type definition for 'evolve' function

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I'm trying to write a simple type definition for `evolve` function from ramda. (https://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve). Official definition does not work correctly.

```
type Transformation<State> = {
  [Key in keyof State]: (x: State[Key]) => any
}

declare function evolve
  <State extends {}, Evolver extends Partial<Transformation<State>>>(evolver: Evolver, state: State):
  {[Key in keyof State]: Evolver[Key] extends (...args: any[]) => {} ? ReturnType<Evolver[Key]> : State[Key]}
```

I'm trying to use that in a generic function:

```
const foo = <State extends {a: string, b: string}>(state: State) => {
  const test = evolve({
    a: x => x,
    b: x => x
  }, state)
}
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
Argument of type '{ a: (x: State["a"]) => State["a"]; b: (x: State["b"]) => State["b"]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Transformation<State>>'.(2345)
```

It's not clear from the error why it's not assignable, so I don't know how to fix that

Comment: For reference, this is what DefinitelyTyped has for `evolve` https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/ramda/index.d.ts#L592

Comment: It feels like you're maybe you're trying to fit this solution to your problem instead of the other way around. What is the problem you're trying to solve with this generic function?

Comment: @ChadS. I use evolve function in many places, so there is no concrete problem, but there is a concrete use case when my definition is not working: when 'State' is generic. And I don't understand why it's not working

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is what is the issue with simply defining foo as:

`const foo = R.evolve({ a: R.identity, b: R.identity});`

Comment: There is no issue in using `identity` function, but it doesn't help here

Comment: Seems like a bug/limitation. Do you really need that generic?

Comment: @H.B. yes, I really need it :)
Actually I have a lot of use cases for this and currently I'm using explicit casting which is not nice

Comment: Would recommend opening an issue in the TypeScript repository or checking if one already exists, might be hard to find though.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there was a couple things going on. I was able to get this to work by lifting `Evolver` in it's own type alias which also avoids an index issue when trying to identify it as the 2nd generic param. I also switched some return types to `unknown` to have ts infer them in the evolver object.

```
type Transformation<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: (x: T[K]) => unknown;
};

type Evolver<State> = Partial<Transformation<State>>;

declare function evolve<State extends { [key: string]: unknown }>(
  evolver: Evolver<State>,
  state: State
): {
  [Key in keyof State]: Evolver<State>[Key] extends (...args: any[]) => infer R
    ? R
    : State[Key];
};

const foo = (state: { a: string; b: string }) => {
  const test = evolve(
    {
      a: (x) => x,
      b: (x) => x,
    },
    state
  );
};
```

Comment: Seems promising, but `infer R` is not working it seems.  Variable `test` should have function properties a and b, but the result is a plain object.

Comment: If state (within foo function) is generic, e.g `<T extends {a: string, b: string}>(state: T)`
It's still not working. But I like the idea of moving Evolver to separate type and removing generic param